# SailsJS - Blueprint associations "add to"

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I would like to use the Blueprint routes to use the "add to" and "remove to" association routes.

I have two models :

stockpile :

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    keys: {
      collection: 'key',
      via: 'stockpile'
    }
  }

};
```

and key :

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: 'noname'
    },
    stockpile: {
      model: 'stockpile'
    }
  }

};
```

I have a stockpile with id 1, and a key with id 1. But when I do :

> POST /stockpile/1/keys/1

I have a 404 error. REST blueprints routes are enabled.

What am I doing wrong ?

Regards,
Sylvain

Comment: Do you have the controllers?

Comment: Yes, I have the controllers. Looks like the problem is only on Windows (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2787)

Answer (score 1):

Are on you Windows ? If yes, that's a [known bug](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2787).